# Should I store large amounts of data in the properties of a node in a graph database?

Tags: database, database-design, graph-databases

I'm building a reddit clone on top of software that must incorporate a legacy neo4j graph database to track user actions. I also want to use it to store the comment/post data. Assuming this new app is basically used like any other content aggregator site, would it be better to store all comment data in each node or only store or a unique ID that links to a *different* database containing the comment data? Each comment is permitted to have up to 50,000 characters (~50kB).

Is there a cutoff of, like, 1,000 characters (~1kB) where it stops making sense to store the data directly in the graph db? Should I be storing the comment data itself as multiple nodes in the graph?

Comment: Why do you want to store comment data in a graph database? What benefits does that bring? What are the drawbacks that you can foresee? I don't think we can judge what "better" means.

Comment: Having one fewer database to deal with would make the entire project an order of magnitude easier to implement. Basically my gut tells me I shouldn't store large amounts of data as properties in each graph node, but I have no rational reason for this belief.

Comment: Properties of an entity are orthogonal to graph complexity. Complexity increases with "dense" nodes, nodes with a lot of edges. Neo4J suffers from the dense node problem, during transactions, i.e all edges of such a node are locked down as well, making it a bottleneck.

Comment: @S.D. you're telling me there is zero impact on database functionality when I store large amounts of data in properties?

Answer (score 5):

I am not a Neo4J expert, but I can tell you how I would approach such an assessment:

1. Ask in a place where you find other Neo4j users and experts: the Neo4J community site looks good for me: https://community.neo4j.com/

   I also found this Q&A on dba.stackexchange which may be helpful: [Amount of data per node in Neo4j](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/amount-of-data-per-node-in-neo4j), still I guess dba.SE, like softwareengineering.SE, is not the place where one can find many experts for Neo4j.
2. Set up a test Neo4j instance and build a small test project which generates test data which is comparable in size and complexity to what you will expect in production. Use it to generate some numbers from it, for example, if performance and memory size will meet your needs.
3. When the test in step #2 looks good, go for implementing it in production, but have a "plan B" at hand - make sure if in production performance starts to degrade over time, or maybe some other effect, you will still have the option of introducing a second database (in case that is *really* the solution for the unexpected issue).

   I guess that introducing a second database right from the start or at a later point in time will not really make huge difference in terms of total effort, so why not start with the simpler solution and switch to the more complex one when you know you really need it? Of course, you should keep the code which accesses the comments on the database level in a central place, but that is something most experienced software engineers would do either, second database in mind or not.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid conducting my own experiment... Some must have figured this out already. I couldn't find anything on neo4j.com and that dba.SE only answers whether it's possible to store large amounts of data, not how performant it is

Comment: @AustinCapobianco: the point is, what you are trying cannot be answered just "for any graph database". The answer may depend on the specifics of Neo4J, maybe depend on the specific version, and most likely depend on your the specific queries which are performed as part of your use case, and also on your use cases' specific performance requirements. Asking others may save you the effort of an experiement when they can tell you that the whole approach makes no sense - but honestly, I don't see a striking argument why it should not work, so IMHO the best is: try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider when you store large text as properties on nodes in Neo4j:

- the size of the database increases on disk. This is something to take into account, as well as the corresponding size of backups and the time to backup and restore
- the corresponding size of indexes should you index these properties.
- pagecache/memory pressure if you're queries collect these nodes with large text, for example

Other than this, there is no impact on graph traversals or such